# Unpublish Android App

Tags: android, developer-console

As I know that there is an option called "UNPUBLISH" in google developer console under APK.

After adding Manage APK google actually removed access to APK.

Unfortunately I uploaded APK in production instead of BETA, I need to remove/unpublish that app.

How can I do it?

What is the best process to solve this issue.

I gone through all questions that are similar to my problem, but all answer are out dated as goolge added Manage APK in place of APK.

Comment: Build a new APK using the same code as the last good version of the app, but with a higher versionCode, then publish that APK?

Comment: @Michael is right. Compile your last good version with a new code, upload it as production and then publish your beta build to the beta channel.

Comment: Thanks I solved it

Answer (score 0):

I added a new Activity (**Sample**), with XML consisting simple TextView (Coming Soon...)

and making **Sample Activity** as LAUNCHER activity in Android Manifeast.xml